# deformation between keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

i am trying some simple animations on blender and keep getting this problem.
between the keyframes that i have set there is suddenly some distortion.
the time before that i got that iwas able to get rid of it by cleaning the keyframes, but not this time.
apologies if that was asked before. i couldnt find an answer so far and i dont know what it is that i am doing wrong.
here is a gif to see my problem.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/I2PONoD.png]

i am thankful fur every kind of help.

[image]

Comment: I can't tell from looking at the .gif, but you may find looking at the animation curves in the "graph editor" window to be helpful. look for extreme peaks or steep slopes. If I had to guess, I would say that your animation is trying to spin to 360 degrees or more, and is instead quickly spinning back to 0 degrees. You can correct that in the graph editor by translating the offending keyframe 360 degrees up or down the y axis.

Comment: you led me to the solution, thank you very much! :)